# Wierd JSON result - Elfinder.NET initialization error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json, elfinder

I'm using ElFinder.NET connector in my MVC applications. In one application everything works fine, but the other application can't initialize Elfinder.

The code used to initialize Elfinder is the same in both applications. The problem is probably in `Connector.Process(this.HttpContext.Request)` call.

In the application, where ElFinder is working, `Connector.Process` returns JSON result with correct data, the other application returns a wierd result.

I can see in the browser, that the request was processed, but the response body contains string `System.Web.Mvc.JsonDataContractResult` instead of JSON data. If I step through the code in Visual Studio, I see that `Connector.Process` return a `JsonDataContractResult` but it's empty.

[image]

Comment: I have same issue :( I can't understand the sample project is running well but mines not.. Have you got any solution?

Comment: Find the solution bro, I updated Json.Net package (Newtonsoft.Json) and it works. I have an older version on my project before, and when i ref DLL's of EIFinder.Net i wasn't taked that dll.. When i updated my solution packages resolve solved :)

Comment: DortGen: Thank you for your suggestion - it works :-) If you post it as an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well then :)

Possible situation is; outdated Json.Net(Newtonsotf.Json) package version. If you have an older version of this library please simply replace them with the ones in elfinder's package as i say on my comment..