# Object becomes unreadable when loaded out of other assembly

Tags: asp.net, json, serialization

Yesterday I found myself dealing with the following problem:
[Wierd JSON result - Elfinder.NET initialization error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19808986/wierd-json-result-elfinder-net-initialization-error) . The solution that questions suggests did not work for me though.

After significant stepping through code I discovered the JsonResult object was being put together just fine, but when my controller fetched it from the class in the elFinder assembly that put it together, my debugger did not seem to know it anymore. All it could show me was the name of the underlying type; none of the properties showed. I verified that

- System.Web.MVC assembly versions matched
- Newtonsoft Json.net assembly versions matched
- bitness matched

Eventually I moved all of the classes in the elFinder assembly into the main web assembly, and everything was peachy keen.

So, what causes an object to lose all of its state (or makes its state unreadable) without any compiler errors or runtime errors or, well, anything? How could I have fixed this without making everything one big assembly?

Comment: You're going to need to show us the code that is not functioning as expected.  We cannot help you to debug code that we cannot see.

Comment: Do you have a reproducible example?